# Error when Building wxWidgets on Ubuntu 14.04 with GTK+ 3

Tags: ubuntu, wxwidgets

I am trying to compile the latest stable release of wxWidgets (3.0.0) on Ubuntu 14.04. When I confiugure `--with-gtk=2`, everything works fine, but when I configure `with-gtk=3`, I get the following error on executing `make`:

```
../src/gtk/toplevel.cpp: In member function ‘bool wxTopLevelWindowGTK::Create(wxWindow*, wxWindowID, const wxString&, const wxPoint&, const wxSize&, long int, const wxString&)’:
../src/gtk/toplevel.cpp:733:78: error: ‘GDK_IS_WAYLAND_SCREEN’ was not declared in this scope
             GDK_IS_WAYLAND_SCREEN(gtk_window_get_screen(GTK_WINDOW(m_widget))) &&
                                                                              ^
make: *** [coredll_gtk_toplevel.o] Error 1
```

Of course, I have installed the `libgtk-3-dev` package.

The `config.log` file is available [here](http://pastebin.com/8w7ihKUC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be fixed in the latest 3.0 branch sources in svn/git, please test them if you can, otherwise please try 3.0.1 when it's released.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the latest 3.0 branch sources worked just fine.